# Replace first value of a cmd in a dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm testing around with docker and try to create own docker images.

My first Dockerfile just take an ubuntu as basic image and installs cowsay.

Dockerfile 1:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cowsay
ENTRYPOINT ["usr/games/cowsay"]
```

I build the image with

```
docker build -t test/cowsay .
```

and can run it with

```
docker run test/cowsay Hello World
```

---

In the next step I would like to create an image which puts default text in cowsay if there is no additional argument with the docker call. For the default text i use fortune.

Dockerfile 2

```
FROM test/cowsay:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install fortune
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD /usr/games/fortune -s | /usr/games/cowsay -f tux
```

I build the image with

```
docker build -t test/fortune .
```

and run it with

```
docker run test/fortune


 ________________________________________
/ You possess a mind not merely twisted, \
\ but actually sprained.                 /
 ----------------------------------------
   \
    \
        .--.
       |o_o |
       |:_/ |
      //   \ \
     (|     | )
    /'\_   _/`\
    \___)=(___/
```

---

But at least I want to use the default text from fortune only if there is no additional argument in the docker call.

If I type

docker run test/fortune Hello

the ***/usr/games/fortune -s*** has to be replaced with ***Hello***.

```
 _______
< Hello >
 -------
   \
    \
        .--.
       |o_o |
       |:_/ |
      //   \ \
     (|     | )
    /'\_   _/`\
    \___)=(___/
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do this using a bash script and `ENTRYPOINT`

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    /usr/games/fortune -s | /usr/games/cowsay -f tux
else
   echo $@ | /usr/games/cowsay -f tux
fi
```